# How to get a version of Eclipse that uses Maven (MVN) 3.2.3 as embedded version of Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a Maven build that will resolve the required dependencies using Maven 3.2.3.  If I use Maven 3.3.9 I get dependency errors.  The version of Eclipse I'm using uses Maven 3.3.9 as the embedded version of Maven.  There is a message in the configuration window that states "Note: Embedded runtime is always used for dependency resolution" so I get dependency errors when the project is build in Eclipse.  How do I get a version of Eclipse that uses Maven 3.2.3 as the embedded version of Maven?  Is there a version of Eclipse I can download that already uses the version of Maven as the embedded version?  Is there a way I can change the embedded version to point to Maven 3.2.3?

Answer (score 1):

Embedded maven is coming from m2e plugin of eclipse. You can find older releases of this plugin in the following link. 
https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/m2e-downloads.html#m2eclipse-releases

In eclipse `Help-> Install new Software` and click Add button; for location copy paste the address next to the plugin version you choose(from the above link). And install the plugin. (You might want to remove your current plugin first before doing this)  I think you might want to check plugin versions from 1.5 to 1.6. (*)

If you cant fix your problem this way, you may have to build the plugin yourself. https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/master/m2e-maven-runtime/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime/pom.xml Inside this pom changing  `<maven-core.version>3.5.3</maven-core.version>` (there is comment about this inside this pom.xml) to desired version and [building the plugin.](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-development-environment.html)

(*) If you want to know which plugin version uses which maven version; Just click the link next to plugin version and `Show Directory Contents-> plugins -> org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_***.jar` and download this jar. Open it with a zip program to see its maven version.(Inside the jar there is a jars folder and maven jars is there)

Comment: There are some release notes at https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-15.html.  Not very detailed but they do provide some information about what version of mvn is used by the release of m2e.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I ended up punting on this.  I moved to InteliJ.  Not being able specify what Maven version to use to resolve resources was a show stopper for Eclipse on the project I was working on that required a specific version of Maven for its dependencies.  It would be a very welcome enhancement to Eclipse to be able to specify the version of Maven to use for dependency resolution.